# what's the relationship between exit(0) and zombie process

Tags: c, linux, zombie-process

I found that it can't create a zombie process when I remove `exit(0);` from the child part. Can you tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
      if(!fork()) {
        printf("child pid=%d\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
      }

      sleep(20);

      printf("parent pid=%d\n",getpid());
      exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zombie process is a dead child process that the parent process hasn’t checked on. In the original code, the child ends 20 seconds earlier than the parent, so it’s a zombie for 20 seconds. If you remove the first `exit(0)`, they both stay alive for 20 seconds because in the child, control passes right out the bottom of the `if` block unless something stops it.

Thus, if you remove the child's `exit()` then not only is it unlikely to go zombie for an observable amount of time, but you should see it print a "parent pid" message in addition to its "child pid" message.